# Is the sequence $(x_n)$ in Gradient Descent algorithm always convergent?

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

> Let $f \in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ be convex and $\nabla f$ be $L$-Lipschitz continuous. The sequence $(x_n)$ in Gradient Descent algorithm is defined as $$x_{n+1} = x_n -\gamma_n \nabla f(x_n)$$ where $\gamma_n>0$ is the step size.

It's is well-known that $(f(x_n))$ will converge to the minimum of $f$. I've searched through my lecture note and many other materials on the Internet, but it seems that they do not mention about the convergence of $(x_n)$. As such,

> I would like to ask if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges.

Thank you so much for your clarification!

Comment: Generally however, if $f$ is bounded below then (depending on your step size rule) you have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \nabla f(x_n) = 0$. But, for example, with $f(x) = e^{-x}$, the iterates will not converge.

Comment: I was thinking of something like the Armijo step size rule.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, I would like to confirm that even with additional assumptions (appropriate step size and $f$ is bounded from below), we are still not sure if $(x_n)$ converges, right?

Comment: Correct, I gave an example in my first comment. The iterates will go to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much @copper.hat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @copper.hat for providing  a counter-example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569418/assume-f-is-convex-and-f-is-lipschitz-continuous-is-the-sequence-x-n-d#comment7339421_3569418).

> Let $f(x)=x$. Then $x_{n+1} = x_n -\gamma$ is divergent for all $\gamma> 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However it can happen that there is no unique minimizer and in that case the limit depends on your starting point. For example for $f(x,y)=x^2$ the second component of the limit is simply the second component of the initial point.

Comment: Could you please suggest me any reference on the proof of it?