# Assume $f$ is convex and $f'$ is Lipschitz continuous. Is the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_0=a$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n+\lambda f'(x_k)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lipschitz-functions

> Assume $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is convex and $f'$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous. We fix $\{a, \lambda\} \subseteq \mathbb R$ and define the sequence $(x_n)$ recursively by $x_0=a$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n+\lambda f'(x_k)$.

I would like to find an example $(f,a,\lambda)$ satisfying above conditions in which the sequence $(x_k)$ is not convergent. Thank you so much!

Comment: You probably should try some basic functions first. $f(x) = x$, $\lambda = 1$ then $x_n= a+n\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you so much @copper.hat :) May you write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: No need. Glad to help.

Comment: So I will write to close this question :)

Comment: I added an answer :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x, \lambda =1$ then $x_n = a + n \lambda$.

Comment: You example also solves this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564427/is-the-sequence-x-n-in-gradient-descent-algorithm-always-convergent/3569470#3569470) too.

Comment: I added a comment to your question that you might find apropros.